# Extracting XML data reverse XSLT?

Tags: c#, xml, xslt, datatable, dataset

I have some XML data that resides in an XML file and I am trying to get it into datatables. I have tried putting it into a Dataset. I have tried putting it in XML nodes. However, it all seems random and just all over the place and it's not working. I have tried to include a summarized version of how the data looks below. How can I extract it into clear tables and rows and columns? Also, I am not sure if this would help or not, but this XML is created from 4 tables that are then extracted to an XML file using and XSLT file. Is there a way to do it in REVERSE to take the XSLT and XML file into the original datatables?

```
<obj name="TableName0">
    <int name="ANumberThatsAColumn1" val="" />
    <int name="ANumberThatsAColumn2" val="" />
    <int name="ANumberThatsAColumn3" val="" />
    <str name="ADateThatsAColumn4" val="2022-12-16T08:43:07.9870485-06:00" />
</obj>


<list name="TableName1">
    <obj href="RowOfData1/">
        <int name="ColName1" val="0" />
        <str name="ColName2" val="1" />
        <int name="ColName3" val="1" />
        <int name="ColName4" val="0" />
        <int name="ColName5" val="6" />
        <int name="ColName6" val="0" />
        <str name="ColName7" val="#3062" />
        <ref name="ColName8" href="SomeValue1" />
    </obj>


    <obj href="RowOfData2/">
        <int name="ColName1" val="0" />
        <str name="ColName2" val="1" />
        <int name="ColName3" val="1" />
        <int name="ColName4" val="0" />
        <int name="ColName5" val="6" />
        <int name="ColName6" val="0" />
        <str name="ColName7" val="#2543" />
        <ref name="ColName8" href="SomeValue2" />
        <int name="ColName9" val="0" />
        <int name="ColName10" val="0" />
        <int name="ColName11" val="0" />
    </obj>
</list>


<list name="TableName2">
    <list name="row1">
        <int name="R0" val="0" displayName="#7925" />
        <int name="R1" val="1" displayName="#7926" />
    </list>
    <list name="row2">
        <int name="R0" val="0" displayName="#21641" />
        <int name="R1" val="1" displayName="#21642" />
        <int name="R2" val="2" displayName="#21643" />
    </list>
</list>
```

Comment: What is your database and its version?

Comment: The database it's created from is Oracle but if I can extract the data in vb.net or c# in an effective, common sense way, I was probably going to put it an a local Access database. I can figure that part out I think pretty easily so long as I can figure out a good extraction method which is what is currently hanging me up. I suspect LINQ could probably be used but I have never used it so it seems daunting at the moment.

Comment: If you can use SQL Server as a target database, it supports XML data type, and XQuery language. So, you can shred XML and load it to db tables in T-SQL.

Comment: I may have access to a SQL Server. What resources would I need to research to go that route?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a conceptual example for you.

XML shredding is happening in T-SQL via two XQuery methods:

- `.node()`
- `.value()`

[XQuery Language Reference (SQL Server)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/xquery/xquery-language-reference-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16)

**SQL**

```
DECLARE @xml XML =
N'<root>
    <obj name="TableName0">
        <int name="ANumberThatsAColumn1" val=""/>
        <int name="ANumberThatsAColumn2" val=""/>
        <int name="ANumberThatsAColumn3" val=""/>
        <str name="ADateThatsAColumn4" val="2022-12-16T08:43:07.9870485-06:00"/>
    </obj>
    <list name="TableName1">
        <obj href="RowOfData1/">
            <int name="ColName1" val="0"/>
            <str name="ColName2" val="1"/>
            <int name="ColName3" val="1"/>
            <int name="ColName4" val="0"/>
            <int name="ColName5" val="6"/>
            <int name="ColName6" val="0"/>
            <str name="ColName7" val="#3062"/>
            <ref name="ColName8" href="SomeValue1"/>
        </obj>
        <obj href="RowOfData2/">
            <int name="ColName1" val="0"/>
            <str name="ColName2" val="1"/>
            <int name="ColName3" val="1"/>
            <int name="ColName4" val="0"/>
            <int name="ColName5" val="6"/>
            <int name="ColName6" val="0"/>
            <str name="ColName7" val="#2543"/>
            <ref name="ColName8" href="SomeValue2"/>
            <int name="ColName9" val="0"/>
            <int name="ColName10" val="0"/>
            <int name="ColName11" val="0"/>
        </obj>
    </list>
    <list name="TableName2">
        <list name="row1">
            <int name="R0" val="0" displayName="#7925"/>
            <int name="R1" val="1" displayName="#7926"/>
        </list>
        <list name="row2">
            <int name="R0" val="0" displayName="#21641"/>
            <int name="R1" val="1" displayName="#21642"/>
            <int name="R2" val="2" displayName="#21643"/>
        </list>
    </list>
</root>';

-- INSRT INTO <targetTable>
SELECT c.value('@name', 'VARCHAR(20)') AS name
    , c.value('@val', 'INT') AS val
    , c.value('@displayName', 'VARCHAR(20)') AS displayName
FROM @xml.nodes('/root/list[@name="TableName2"]/list/int') AS t(c);

-- INSRT INTO <targetTable>
SELECT c.value('@name', 'VARCHAR(20)') AS name
    , c.value('@val', 'VARCHAR(20)') AS val
    , c.value('@href', 'VARCHAR(20)') AS href
FROM @xml.nodes('/root/list[@name="TableName1"]/obj/*') AS t(c);
```